# Unresponsive Android BroadcastReceiver in Phonegap Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am in the process of creating a Phonegap plugin which, amongst other things, allows me to setup an alarm. My understanding of how this should be done is as follows:

- Setup a pending intent, PI, that the OS can use to "dial back" the app
- Declare that intent in the plugin.xml file
- Request an alarm
- Wait for the OS to use the PI to dial back the app.

To that end here is the code I have written:

- The **plugin.xml** file

  ```
  <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
  <feature name="Pall">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.example.Plugin"/>
  </feature>
  </config-file>

  <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <receiver android:name="com.example.plugin.ServiceAlarm" 
   android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.example.plugin.ServiceAlarm" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  </config-file>
  ```

Extend the **Broadcast receiver class** - file ServiceAlarm.java

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class ServiceAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
 {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
   Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
   //in a real world app one would do a whole lot more here      
  }
 }
```

Define the plugin - file plugin.java

```
package com.example.plugin;
//various imports
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import ...

 public class Plugin extends CordovaPlugin 
 {
  private Context context;

  @Override
  public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) 
  {
   super.initialize(cordova, webView);
   this.context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
  }

  public void makeToast(String msg)
  {
   Toast.makeText(this.context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
  }

  private boolean setAlarm(final CallbackContext cbc,Context ctxt,JSONArray data)
  {
   try
   {    
    makeToast("Setting alarm");

    Intent intent = new Intent(ctxt,ServiceAlarm.class);
    intent.setAction("com.example.plugin.ServiceAlarm");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent =  
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt,1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager =    
    (AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10000,pendingIntent);
    makeToast("Alarm Set");
    cbc.success("Set!");
    return true;
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
     cbc.error("Failed!");
     return false;
    } 
  }
```

Catch method calls coming in across the JS bridge:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext cbc)  
throws JSONException 
{
 Context ctxt = this.context;
 try
 {   
  switch(action)
  {
    case "setalarm":return setAlarm(cbc,ctxt,data);
    default:cbc.error(action + " is not known");return false;       
  }   
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
  cbc.error(e.getMessage() + "xx");
  return false;   
 }  
}
```

}

Define the Cordova JS bridge. File plugin.js:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
var plugin = 
{
 setalarm:function (scbk, ecbk) {exec(scbk, ecbk, "Plugin", "setalarm", 
 []);}
};

module.exports = plugin;
```

With all of this in place, I created a Phonegap project in Phonegap CLI using the jquery-mobile-starter template:

```
phonegap create /path/to/project --template jquery-mobile-starter
```

Then I added the plugin:

```
phonegap plugin add /path/to/plugin
```

And after that I modified the `init` method in `app.js`:

```
function init() 
{
 alert('Init');
 try
 { 
  alert('setting alarm');
  plugin.setalarm(success,failure);
  alert('alarm set');
 } catch(e){alert('error' + e.message);}
}


function success(msg){alert(msg);}
function failure(msg){alert('Error ' + msg);}
```

As far as I can tell at this point, I have done all of the following:

- Created a plugin
- Exposed a method from this plugin to trigger an alarm 10 seconds after it has been set
- Created a broadcast receiver to handle alarm events sent down by the OS
- Declared the intent to handle such events in the app manifest file
- Created an app that uses this plugin
- From the `init` method for the app set the alarm

The app complies correctly and when started up fires up all the various diagnostic toasts that I have coded in. However, it **never** responds to the actual alarm event.

Clearly, I am doing something wrong here or have misunderstood how the system handles alarms. I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to put me on the right track.

+++++++++++++

> Since posting this question I have found that if I register the broadcast receiver dynamically things work as expected.

```
  final String SOME_ACTION = "com.example.plugin.ServiceAlarm";
  IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SOME_ACTION);
  ServiceAlarm mReceiver = new ServiceAlarm(this.context);
  ctxt.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
  Intent intent = new Intent(SOME_ACTION);
```

The clear difference here is that instead of passing the ServiceAlarm **class** to the Intent constructor I am passing an instance of the ServiceAlarm object itself.

The fact that this works is very comforting but it leaves a question - I have run into scores of examples that do things the "other way", i.e. my original way.  So are they wrong or do I have an error somewhere in my code - e.g. the Receiver declaration in the config.xml file.

I am hoping that someone here might be able to spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be in plugin.xml. **Receiver** have to be a child of **application**. The issue can be fixed by moving *receiver* to separate *config-file* with ***application*** parent:

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*/application">
    <receiver android:name="com.example.plugin.ServiceAlarm" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.plugin.ServiceAlarm" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</config-file>
```